# AngularJS : How to pass an object from the directive to transcluded template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a directive that creates a UI that allows the user to perform a search. The directive wraps content which will transclude and become the template for each individual search result. Something like this:

```
<search>
  <div class="someStyle" ng-click="selectResult(result)">{{result.Name}}</div>
</search>
```

I'd like the ng-click to call the selectResult function on the controller's scope, but have the `result`  object come from the directive. How can I accomplish this with an isolated scope in the directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using ng-transclude, you can build your own search transclude directive that can be used to put result onto the transcluded scope. For example, your search directive might look something like this with ng-repeat and the search-transclude directive where you want the transcluded content:

```
.directive("search", function (SearchResults) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div ng-repeat="result in results">Search Relevance:' +
        '{{result.relevance}}' +
        //the most important part search-transclude that receives the current
        //result of ng-repeat
        '<div search-transclude result="result"></div></div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //get search results
            scope.results = SearchResults.results;
        }
    }
})
```

Build search transclude directive as follows:

```
.directive("searchTransclude", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
            //create a new scope that inherits from the parent of the
            //search directive ($parent.$parent) so that result can be used with other
            //items within that scope (e.g. selectResult)
            var newScope = scope.$parent.$parent.$new();
            //put result from isolate to be available to transcluded content
            newScope.result = scope.$eval(attrs.result);
            $transclude(newScope, function (clone) {
                elem.append(clone);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

The transcluded content will now be able to see selectResult function if it exists in the scope where the search directive was created. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jjmabdxj/).

Comment: I'm trying to work your example into my code, but $transclude is undefined. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using a controller in the search directive, could that be causing problems?

Comment: I'm also using nested ng-repeats. Maybe that's causing it, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: No, what you assumed was correct, I just also have a controller in the directive and thought maybe that was causing a problem, but I took it out and the 5th parameter is still coming in as 'undefined'. I'm using version 1.2.15. Do you think that since I'm using nested ng-repeats that I'll need to use nested searchTransclude directives as well?

Comment: Maybe add transclude: true to the search-transclude directive. I had transclude: true on the search directive itself in my example. That needs to be set in order to be provided the transcludeFn.

Comment: Adding `transclude: true` on search-transclude worked to get $transclude to not be undefined, but I'm still not seeing my content. I don't understand why your jsfiddle worked without transclude: true on search-transclude and my code didn't.

Comment: When I step through the code and look at `elem` it is `<div search-transclude result="result"></div>` but `clone` is also `<div search-transclude result="result"></div>`. So it's like it's appending itself to itself. I'm so confused.

Comment: Can you put what you are doing on jsfiddle so I can see what is going on. The example I gave works, but can't elaborate further without seeing your setup.

Comment: I FINALLY figured it out. transclude:true is not needed on search-transclude. The problem was being caused by an `ng-show` on the outer ng-repeat! The expression was true, its mere existence was causing an error! I tried moving it to a parent div, but still had problems. Only after I changed it to an ng-if did the $transclude function and the content come through. I have no idea why that was a problem but at least I got it working. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I had to add another `.$parent` in search-transclude because of the nested ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Transcluded content will always use the scope in which the directive element resides, i.e. your controller scope. That's why if you want the `result` argument of `selectResult` function to get it's value from isolated scope, then you need to establish two way binding between isolated scope's and controller scope's `result` properties. After setting the `result` property to desired value in isolated scope the controller's scope `result` property will be updated to the same value. So , transcluded content will use controller's `result` which is in sync with isolated scope's `result`.

1) add `resultAttr='result'` attribute to directive element.

`<search resultAttr='result'>
  <div class="someStyle" ng-click="selectResult(result)">{{result.Name}}</div>
</search>`

2) establish two-way binding for `result` property when you define isolated scope in directive:

`scope: {
    result: "=resultAttr"
}`

3) set `result` to some value in directive

Comment: I want to do an ng-repeat in the directive template and use the transcluded content as a template for each result. In your example, wouldn't they all be using the same result object?

Comment: for ng-repeat case it will not work because ng-repeat wil create it's own scope as child scope of directive's scope and all `result` properties from each iteration of ng-repeat will be in new child scope of directive.

Comment: do you have any reason to use transclusion here?

Comment: Because I want to reuse the searching directive, but allow the consumer of the directive to format the results however they want.

Comment: you can try to get rid of isolated scope of directive and set directive's scope to be inherited from controller(set `scope: true` in your directive). Then change the `<div class="someStyle" ng-click="selectResult(result)">{{result.Name}}</div>` to `<div class="someStyle" ng-click="selectResult($$child.$$child.result)">{{$$child.$$child.result.Name}}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like the ng-click [in the directive] to call the selectResult
>   function on the controller's scope...

1. To pass functions (or properties) into an isolate scope, you use attributes on the directive tag.

> ...but have the result object come from the directive [scope].

2. If you want the contents of a directive tag to have access to the directive's scope, you DON'T use transclude.  Specifying `transclude: true` tells angular NOT to allow the contents of a directive tag to have access to the directive's scope--the opposite of what you want.

**To accomplish #1**, you could make the user specify the template like this:

```
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <search external-func='selectResult'>
      <div class="someStyle" ng-click="selectResult(result)">{{result.Name}}</div>
    </search>

  </div>
```

Note, the user needs to add an extra attribute to the `<search>` tag.  Yet, that html may comport better with angular's philosophy that the html should give hints to the developer about what javascript will operate on the elements.

Then you specify the isolate scope like this:

```
      scope: {
        selectResult: '=externalFunc'
      },
```

**To accomplish #2**, don't specify `transclude: true` in the directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectResult = function(result) {
    console.log("In MainCtrl: " + result.Name);
  };

}]);

app.controller('DirectiveCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.results = [ 
    {Name: "Mr. Result"},
    {Name: "Mrs. Result"}
  ]

}]);

app.directive('search', function() {

  return {
      restrict: 'E',

      scope: {
        selectResult: '=externalFunc'
      },

      template: function(element, attrs) {
      //                    ^       ^
      //                    |       |
      //    directive tag --+       +-- directive tag's attributes

        var inner_div = element.children();
        inner_div.attr('ng-repeat', 'result in results')

        //console.log("Inside template func: " + element.html());

        return element.html();  //Must return a string.  The return value replaces the innerHTML of the directive tag.
      },

      controller: 'DirectiveCtrl'
  }

}]);
```

The html could provide an even better record of what the javascript does if you make the user specify their template in more detail:

```
<search external-func='selectResult'>
  <div class="someStyle" 
    ng-click="selectResult(result)"
    ng-repeat="result in results">{{result.Name}}
  </div>
</search>
```

#### But if you insist on the minimalist html:

```
<search>
  <div class="someStyle" ng-click="selectResult(result)">{{result.Name}}</div>
</search>
```

...then you can dynamically add the ng-repeat attribute(as shown above), and it's also possible to dynamically map an external function to the isolate scope:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectDog = function(result) {
    console.log("In MainCtrl: you clicked " + result.Name);
  };

  $scope.greet = function(result) {
    console.log('MainCtrl: ' + result.Name);
  };

}]);

app.controller('DirectiveCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.results = [ 
    {Name: "Mr. Result"},
    {Name: "Mrs. Result"}
  ]

}]);

app.directive('search', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',

    scope: {
      externalFunc: '&externalFunc'  //Cannot write => externalFunc: '&'
    },                               //because the attribute name is
                                     //'external-func', which means
                                     //the left hand side would have to be external-func.
    template: function(element, attrs) {
      //Retrieve function specified by ng-click:
      var inner_div = element.children();
      var ng_click_val = inner_div.attr('ng-click'); //==>"selectResult(result)"

      //Add the outer_scope<==>inner_scope mapping to the directive tag:
      //element.attr('external', ng_click_val); //=> No worky! Angular does not create the mapping.
      //But this works:
      attrs.$set('externalFunc', ng_click_val) //=> external-func="selectResult(result)"
      //attrs.$set('external-func', ng_click_val); //=> No worky!

      //Change ng-click val to use the correct call format:
      var func_args = ng_click_val.substring(ng_click_val.indexOf('(')); //=> (result)
      func_args =  func_args.replace(/[\(]([^\)]*)[\)]/, "({$1: $1})"); //=> ({result: result})
      inner_div.attr('ng-click', 'externalFunc' + func_args); //=> ng-click="externalFunc({result: result})"

      //Dynamically add an ng-repeat attribute:
      inner_div.attr('ng-repeat', 'result in results')

      console.log("Template: " + element[0].outerHTML);
      return element.html();
    },

    controller: 'DirectiveCtrl'
  }
})
```

If you want to call the external function with more than one argument, you can do this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.selectResult = function(result, index) {
    console.log("In MainCtrl: you clicked " 
                 +  result.Name 
                 + " " 
                 + index);
  };

}]);

app.controller('DirectiveCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.results = [ 
    {Name: "Mr. Result"},
    {Name: "Mrs. Result"}
  ]

}]);

app.directive('search', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',

    scope: {
      external: '='
    },

    template: function(element, attrs) {
      //Extract function name specified by ng-click:
      var inner_div = element.children();
      var ng_click_val = inner_div.attr('ng-click'); //=>"selectResult(result, $index)"
      var external_func_name =  ng_click_val.substring(0, ng_click_val.indexOf('(') ); //=> selectResult
      external_func_name = external_func_name.trim();

      //Add the outer_scope<==>inner_scope mapping to the directive tag:
      //element.attr('externalFunc', ng_click_val); => No worky!
      attrs.$set('external', external_func_name);  //=> external="selectResult"

      //Change name of ng-click function to 'external':
      ng_click_val = ng_click_val.replace(/[^(]+/, 'external');
      inner_div.attr('ng-click', ng_click_val);

      //Dynamically add ng-repeat to div:
      inner_div.attr('ng-repeat', 'result in results');

      console.log("Template: " + element[0].outerHTML);
      return element.html();
    },

    controller: 'DirectiveCtrl'
  }
});
```

Comment: What I don't like about this approach is that the directive must have knowledge of the implementation of the template in order to work. What if there were two different functions I wanted to call? I shouldn't have to change the directive to do that. Maybe there's a way to pass the scope itself into the directive so that any function could be called from the template?

Comment: @adam0101, The directive does not need to know anything about the template--unfortunately I screwed up my variable names, so changing the function name in the template doesn't work.  I'll post the necessary corrections.

Comment: But you've hard-coded it to only one function and it has to be an ng-click. What if I want one function to select, and another function that shows more details on mouseover? I'd have to change the directive. But I think you're onto something. If I passed `external` an object that encapsulated all the functions I'd want to call, couldn't I get to those functions in the template by doing `ng-click="external.mySelectFunction()"`?

Comment: *But you've hard-coded it to only one function.* No. The template(i.e. the <div>) can specify any function name, and then the corresponding function will be called in the external controller. *and it has to be an ng-click.* Can you point to anything you posted that stated (or implied) that you wanted a function name NOT specified by ng-click to be called in the external scope?

Comment: No, the directive as you've written it can only accept one function. What if I want 6 different buttons in the template? I shouldn't have to state or imply that a directive shouldn't need explicit knowledge of how the consumer of that directive is going to implement the template. The accepted answer doesn't have that limitation and I think your answer wouldn't either if you changed `external` to be an object that encapsulates any possible function the template may want to call.